# Django, overriding "is_authenticated()" when we have Email instead of username

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication, django-email

I'm using the `django-email-as-username` app for using email rather than username for authentication, and it works like a charm.

Now, in **view** I want to call

```
if request.user.is_authenticated()
```

but this method just authenticate users based upon (username+password) and not (email+password). How should I deal with this ?

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Django the `is_authenticated()` always returns `True` for `User` instances and always returns `False` for `AnonymousUser` instances. It has nothing to do with username/password/email and `django-email-as-username` does not change this behaviour.

See the Django's [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L279):

```
# In User class line 279
def is_authenticated(self):
    """
    Always return True. This is a way to tell if the user has been
    authenticated in templates.
    """
    return True
```